# wrong offset with DWARF info

Tags: debugging

The offset of variable I got from DIE info with DWARF is:

```
 <2><c6>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_variable)

    <c7>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xc7): index

    <cb>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1

    <cb>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 6

    <cc>   DW_AT_decl_column : 9

    <cd>   DW_AT_type        : <0x58>

    <d1>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 58  (DW_OP_fbreg: -40)
```

**the offset is -40.**

I printed the memory address of the variable that I want to find his value:

```
printf("%d %p\n", index, &index);
```

and got:

**555555 0x7fff66895018**

I printed the rbp and rsp values:

**rsp: 0x7fff66895010, rbp: 0x7fff66895030**

I noticed that every run the offset from rsp is +8 and from rbp is -18.

How its makes sense? my offset from DIE is wrong?

Thanks for helps!